# For loop Logic Problems with PHP

Tags: php, logic

This is my new code, its almost working, but I think my while loop is wrong some where?

Same as before, gets users taken sick puts it into a var. Then get users entitlement based on years of service, then work out what they have taken and see if the user has used all the full entitlement, then to see if they have used all there half pay entitlement.

Please Help?

```
if($this->CURRENT_USER['User']['role_id'] > 3) { //locks out user types

        //Get Holidaytypes
        $types = $this->Holiday->find(
            'all',
            array(
             'conditions' => array(
                                 'Holiday.holidaystype_id' => 3,
                                 'Holiday.user_id' => $id
             )));

        //Get starting date
        $contracts = $this->Holiday->User->Contract->find(
            'all',
            array(
                'conditions' => array(
                'Contract.user_id' => $id//$data['user_id']),
                'order' => array('Contract.startson' => 'ASC')
            )
        );
    //Get How Many sick days
    foreach ($types as $key => $value) {
            global $SickTotal; 
            $typesDataEnds =  strftime ("%u-%d-%Y", $types[$key]['Holiday']['endson']);
            $typesDataStarts = strftime ("%u-%d-%Y", $types[$key]['Holiday']['startson']);

            $SickTotal = count($typesDataEnds - $typesDataStarts);  
            //echo $SickTotal;

        //Get Contract Start & End Dates
        $start = array_shift($contracts);
        $end = array_pop($contracts);

        $endDate = $end['Contract']['endson'];
        $startDate = $start['Contract']['startson'];

        if (empty($endDate)) {
                $endDate = time('now');
        }
        if (!empty($startDate)) {
            $SortEnd = strftime("%Y", $endDate);
            $SortStart = strftime("%Y", $startDate);
            $YearsService = $SortEnd - $SortStart;

            if ($YearsService <= 1) {
                    $SetFullEntitlement = 5;
                    $SetHalfEntitlement = 5;
                    //echo 'one year';
            } elseif ($YearsService >= 2) {
                    $SetFullEntitlement = 10;
                    $SetHalfEntitlement = 10;
                    //echo 'two years';
            } elseif ($YearsService >= 5) {
                    $SetFullEntitlement = 20;
                    $SetHalfEntitlement = 20;
                    //echo 'up to five years';
            } elseif ($YearsService > 5) {
                    $SetFullEntitlement = 30;
                    $SetHalfEntitlement = 30;
                    //echo 'five years or more';
            } else {
                    $SetFullEntitlement = 0;
                    $SetHalfEntitlement = 0;
                    //echo 'no sick pay';
            }
        } else {
            $YearsService = 0;
            //echo 'Sorry No Start Date For You Found!';
        }

        while ($SickTotal > 0) {
            if ($SetFullEntitlement != 0) {
                $SetFullEntitlement--;
            } elseif ($SetHalfEntitlement != 0) {
                $SetHalfEntitlement--;
            }
        }

        echo 'FullPay:';
        echo $SetFullEntitlement;
        echo '<br/><br/>Halpay:';
        echo $SetHalfEntitlement;
        echo $SickTotal;
    } 

        debug($types);
        die();  
        //$this->render('/artists/holidayslist');

    }       
}
```

Comment: You're missing an $i in your first inner for loop at any rate...

Comment: just because you put question marks at the end of statement , does not turn it into a question

Comment: http://www.antiifcampaign.com/ :)

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking. Also if it's not about the `if`s just leave them out for clarity. Could you elaborate what you want / what doesn't work instead of "I don't seem to be able to get right"?

Comment: That is not valid PHP code at all which makes your question again harder to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I follow exactly what you are trying to do here but you could tidy up your code a bit and save on lines of code. I assume that `$startdate` is how many years ago the user started.

```
$sickdays= array( 0=>5, 1=>10, 2=>20, 5=>30 );
$userdays= 0;
foreach ( array_keys( $sickdays ) as $years_service )
{
   if ( $years_service <= $startdate )
      $userdays=$sickdays[$years_service];
}
```

Now `$userdays` should be the correct number of paid sick days and half days ( the two are always the same in your example ) for this user. A simple comparison should be sufficient to check whether they have taken less or more than their allotted number of days and half days.

I haven't tried this as I'm not working with PHP today, so I'm sure someone will shoot me down directly, but by setting your variables once and writing fewer lines you should find your code gets easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

```
If ($startdate <= 1 year) {
```

If that's literally what you've typed, it's not going to work. Maybe strtotime might make some sense of it?

In any case,

```
 For ($i = $Totalsick, $i >= $Fulldays, $i--) {
    For ($i = $Totalsick, $>= $Halfdays, $i--) {
```

you're missing an $i in there - you're evaluating nothing against $Halfdays. You're also using $i for two seperate loops, so they're both on the same counter. switch your second loop to use a different variable.

Comment: Sorry, must have miss that i and I am only working on logic, so I do know that its pseudo code / php, just trying out my logic.